# Spring Boot: how to implement workflow as synchronous REST services integrating external applications

Tags: spring-boot, workflow, integration, orchestration

I'm here to ask you for a suggestion on which technology to use to add new features on an existing application based on Spring Boot.

The new features consist of some workflows, exposed as synchronous REST services, that must update the database and call REST services exposed by external applications, which consequently will update their own database.

For example, a service could implement this workflow:

1. insert rows in database
2. call the REST service of the application X, which will update its database
3. update rows in database
4. call the REST service of the application Y, which will update its database
5. update rows in database

This workflow must be synchronous and it is started from an human operator that will receive the outcome in few seconds.
If, for example, the step 4) fails, I need to:

- make a compensation, calling another REST service of the application X, in order to undo what it made in step 2)
- rollback the insert/update made in my database in steps 1) and 3)

Which `technology`, `framework`, `tool` or other would you use? In the past I implemented a similar scenario using `Oracle SOA`, but in this case I would avoid to introduce a new infrastructure in my application based on `Spring Boot`.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to learn a bit more about [Spring Framework](https://spring.io/) and [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot).

`1.insert rows in database` : [Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data)

`2.call the REST service of the application X, which will update its database` : A `Http Client` such as [RestTemplate](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) or [WebClient](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/)

`3.update rows in database` : Spring Data JPA (again)

`4.call the REST service of the application Y, which will update its database update rows in database` : RestTemplate...

So so and so...

If you want to make a real workflow, you can use [Activiti](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/08/getting-started-with-activiti-and-spring-boot).